# SmartSVN: How to branch-off working copy from trunk

Tags: ios, macos, svn, smartsvn

I am using SmartSVN 6.6 on my Mac OS X 10.8. I need to create new branch from working copy in trunk of my iOS project. Can anybody explain steps needed for that??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A branch in Subversion is nothing more than a copy.

```
svn cp URL_TO_TRUNK URL_TO_BRANCH
svn switch . URL_TO_BRANCH
```

See also below links:

- http://www.svnforum.org/threads/30924-howto-branch-working-copy-changes-without-committing
- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create

Answer (score 4):

There is also a quick method, that I have learnt using SmartSVN in which you can branch-off code without using terminal.

Step 1: Create a folder in your branches folder and give whatever name you want to give.

Step 2: Add folder to repository by selecting folder and clicking Add button.

Step 3: Right Click your project from your trunk folder and select Copy option.

Step 4: Choose your destination folder you have just created.

Step 5: select options for new branch and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Open Terminal

1] Create Empty Folder on desktop

2] cd desktop folder path svn checkout server path

3] svn checkout server path

There was one folder created on your blank desktop folder like your folder name is AR then one subfolder created automatically ARTEMP.

4] cd subfoldername/

5]copy your code in your subfolder.

6] svn status
Subfolders are display EX. TEMP

7] svn add code foldername(TEMP)

8] svn commit -m "push code"

Committing transaction... Committed revision 1.

Thats It.